# Java - Variable Type specified in class

Tags: java, arrays, variables, types

I found an example in which a box of variables was generated defined by a class similar to this:

```
public class CRandom {
    public String var1;
    public double var2;   
}
```

Then a variable with the 'class'-type was created:

```
CRandom box = new CRandom();
```

To this box all variables could be added:

```
box.var1 = "hello";
box.var2 = 1.234;
```

Instead of adding single variables I would like to add arrays, like this:

```
box.var1[0] = "hello";
box.var2[0] = 1.234;
```

I hope someone can make sense out of my problem as I understand too little to phrase it appropriately and don't know any terms to search for it.

Comment: Can't you just make the fields in `CRandom` be arrays, if that's what you want?

Comment: Or even more flexible: use some [`List` Implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: I should have mentioned that. I amended CRandom to
"public class CRandom {
    public String[] var1;
    public double[] var2;   
}"
Did not solve the problem.

Comment: If the two fields at the same index are related to each other, then you probably want an array (or list) of `CRandom`, rather than a `CRandom` containing two arrays. Parallel arrays are iffy design.

Comment: What concrete problem are you facing? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? My guess is that you're getting a NullPointerException. If so, read the stack trace of the exception. Read the javadoc of NullPointerException. Google for "what is a NullPointerException".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

```
CRandom[] crandoms = new CRandom[10];
crandoms[0] = new CRandom();
crandoms[0].var1 = "hello";
crandoms[0].var2 = 1.234;
```

Or:

```
public class CRandom {
    public String[] vars1;
    public double[] vars2;   
}
CRandom box = new CRandom();
box.vars1 = new String[10];
box.vars2 = new double[10];
box.vars1[0] = "hello";
box.vars2[0] = 1.234;
```

Depending on what `CRandom` represents.

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking encapsulation rules, which is a key tenant of an Object Oriented programming language like Java.  Better to encapsulate the variables and hide the implementation with some interface methods as such:

```
public class CDRandom {

    List<String> var1= new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> var2= new ArrayList<>();

    private void addVar1(String val){
        var1.add(val);
    }
    private void addVar2(String val){
        var2.add(val);
    }
}
```

...

```
CDRandom box= new CDRandom();
box.addVar1("someval");
```

...

That way you can change the internal way the values are stored/handled or calculated without the rest of the program knowing how its done.